# https is not working in nginx along with apache ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl, https, apache2

I'm running with nginx in port 81 and apache in port 80. I tried to put ssl certificate in nginx. It's not woking.

Here is my nginx's default:

```
server{
listen  81;
listen 443 ssl;

 server_name 35.154.225.46;
 ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key;

 location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

I created ssl certificate by following this tutorial: [How To Create an SSL Certificate on Nginx for Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssl-certificate-on-nginx-for-ubuntu-14-04)

Edit: 
Before I was tried to use SSL. I was using nginx [node js] at port 81 and apache [php] at port 80. Now I tried to use SSL in nginx. Now Nginx is working in default port [80] with ssl and apache is not working. I want both server should run.

Comment: define `not working`. What is the error message you get when you try to connect to the server?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider `This site can’t provide a secure connection`

Comment: Thats a protocol error. Are you using SHA1?

Comment: @mzhaase `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

Comment: It works for me, I just get untrusted CA error, because it is self-signed.

Comment: @mzhaase what is working?

Comment: I connected to your site with chrome, and it is working fine.

Comment: @mzhaase yeah It's working  but it's supposed to be work in port 81. port 80 is in use (apache2). Now apache is not working. before apcahe working in 80 and nginx working in port 81.

Comment: Please post full problem description what is not 'working', and describe what 'not working' means. Also post error and access logs from nginx.

Comment: Side note: Why are you trying to use nginx in the first place? If you have apache already running, and nginx is only there to proxy requests through to the node.js server behind, why don't you just configure the existing apache to proxy the requests?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I thought I Couldn't use both PHP and node js at same apache server So I tried with nginx with different port.

Comment: Well, you can. As long as you have a context (subdomain,vhost,port,path) to distinguish it from the php content.

Comment: If that possible to use both node and php at same server would be relief to me. kindly guide me.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider

Comment: @GeraldSchneider you answer worked. I restarted apache. Apache also working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You configured Port 441 for ssl. Port 81 is still configured to use http. If you try to connect to your port 81 with https, you get the protocol error because the server talks plain http, but the client expects an ssl response.

If you want to use ssl on the port 81 you have to add the `ssl` keyword.

```
listen 81 ssl;
```